# Fastest way to handle nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, dictionary, coding-efficiency

I'm new to python and I'm trying to learn the best ways to write very fast code. I'm working on an exercise of handling nested dictionaries, and here is the dictionary that I'm working with:

```
{
    "key_1": [
        {
            "title": <title>,
            "date": <date>,
            "text": <text>
        }
    ],
    "key_2": [
        {
             "title": <title>,
            "date": <date>,
            "text": <text>
        }
     ],
    "key_3": [
            {
                 "title": <title>,
                "date": <date>,
                "text": <text>
            }
     ]
}
```

Here is the code that I've written to access it. But because I have three nested for loops, I don't think this is as fast as it could be:

```
for main_key, main_value in dictionary.items():
    if main_value:
        for value in main_value:
            for sub_keys, sub_values in value.items():
                if sub_keys == "date":
                   print(sub_values)
```

Any pointers on how I can make my code both more concise and faster? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/dictquery/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few points:

1. The `main_key` variable from your main loop is unused, so you can simply iterate over `dictionary.values()` instead.
2. The `if main_value:` statement is redundant because the following `for` loop won't iterate if `main_value` is empty anyway.
3. The innermost loop over `value.items()` is unnecessary because all it's doing is to find the `date` key of the `value` dict and print its value, which you can accomplish by simply using square brackets to access the `value` dict by the `date` key. Put a `try` block around it to ignore a missing `date` key because that's how your current code behaves.

With the above points taken, your code should look like:

```
for main_value in dictionary.values():
    for value in main_value:
        try:
            print(value['date'])
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function and return value:

```
>>> def get_value(key1, key2=None):
...     if key1 and key2:
...         try:
...             return my_dict.get(key1).get(key2)
...         except Exception as e:
...             print(e)
...             return None
...     else:
...         return my_dict(key1)
```

And I can see in your code you want to access only `date` key. you can do like below:

```
>>> for x in my_dict:
...     print(my_dict[x].get('date'))
```

This is fastest you can do. Because time complexity of accessing the value of dictionary is o(1).